# crop circles detected from imfindcircles in matlab

Tags: matlab, crop, geometry

I'm detecting circles from an image using imfindcircles function.
Below is the code.
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwBQo.png)

```
  img= imread('image.png');
  imshow(img);
  rmin=10
  rmax=50
  [centersDarkl, radiiDarkl]=imfindcircles(img, 
  [rmin,rmax],'ObjectPolarity','dark','Sensitivity',0.80);
  viscircles(centersDarkl, radiiDarkl,'LineStyle','--')
```

Now, I want to crop the detected circles and save them as different figures.

Comment: do you want to upload image.jpg so we can try help?

Comment: I have edited the post and added the image

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works for this image. I used floor and ceil to avoid the edges and rmax had to be larger than 75.

```
[img,map] = imread('MwBQo.png','png');
img = ind2rgb(img, map);
figure;
imshow(img);
rmin = 10;
rmax = 80;
[centersDarkl, radiiDarkl] = imfindcircles(img,...
    [rmin,rmax],'ObjectPolarity','dark','Sensitivity',0.80);
viscircles(centersDarkl, radiiDarkl,'LineStyle','--')
for iCirc = 1:size(centersDarkl,1)
    cropped{iCirc,1} =  img(...
        ceil(centersDarkl(iCirc,2)-radiiDarkl(iCirc)):...
        floor(centersDarkl(iCirc,2)+radiiDarkl(iCirc)),...
        ceil(centersDarkl(iCirc,1)-radiiDarkl(iCirc)):...
        floor(centersDarkl(iCirc,1)+radiiDarkl(iCirc)),:);
end

figure;
subplot(1,2,1)
imshow(cropped{1})
subplot(1,2,2)
imshow(cropped{2})
```